# Add product details in custom table when publish a product (WordPress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

That's my code which I wrote in `function.php`:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'send_new_post', 9876543210, 3);

function send_new_post($new_status, $old_status, $post) {

    if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $post->post_type === 'product') {
            
        global $wpdb;
        
        $current_product_id = $post->ID;
        
        if(isset($current_product_id)) {
            $post_id = $current_product_id; 
        } else {
            $post_id = '131';
        }
        
        
        $sql = "SELECT 
                    post_id as id,
                    (SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE id = pm.post_id) AS title,
                    (SELECT post_name  FROM wp_posts WHERE id = pm.post_id) AS name,
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_price' LIMIT 1) AS price, 
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_regular_price' LIMIT 1) AS 'regular_price', 
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_stock' LIMIT 1) AS stock, 
                    IFNULL((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_sku' LIMIT 1),
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key = '_custom_field' LIMIT 1)) as sku


                    FROM `wp_postmeta` AS pm
                    JOIN wp_posts AS p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
                    WHERE p.ID = ".$post_id." AND meta_key in ('_product_version')
                    AND p.post_status in ('publish')";
            
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        $result = json_decode(json_encode($results), true);
        
        $data_init = $result[0];

        $tablename=$wpdb->prefix.'product_init';
            
        $data=array(
            'post_id'       => $data_init['id'],
            'post_title'    => $data_init['title'],
            'post_name'     => $data_init['name'],
            'price'         => $data_init['price'],
            'regular_price' => $data_init['regular_price'],
            'sku'           => $data_init['sku'],
            'stock'         => $data_init['stock'],
            'created_by'    => 'Created By Custom Code' 
        );
        
        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data);
    }
}
```

When I add a product I get the result below, where a few values are missing.

[image]

I can not understand why I am not getting the other values (price, regular_price, sku and stock).
How can I get those too?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using custom queries and updating metadata outside the WooCommerce Product API because looking at the changes WooCommerce trying to optimize the database and your code will stop works after some update. The best and easier way to use methods from the [WC_Product class](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html).

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
$product->set_sku( 'qwe-123' );
$product->set_stock_quantity( 15 );
$product->set_regular_price( 123 )
$product->set_price( 123 );
$product->save();
```

Comment: I need to save publish products in a different table also... that I need to pull data when product update...